# How to concat tuple，which tuples are in bag

Tags: apache-pig

data:

```
1   a   1
1   b   2
2   c   3
2   a   4
```

With the following commands:

```
record = LOAD 'test_in' AS (id:int, company:chararray, rank:chararray);
grp = GROUP record BY id;
```

I got the grp:

```
(1,{(b,2),(a,1),(d,1)})
(2,{(a,4),(c,3)})
```

and I want to get the results as follow:

```
(1,b:2_a:1)
(2,a:4_c:3)
```

Following code returns error:

```
newdata = FOREACH grp GENERATE group AS id,
      BagToString(CONCAT(record.$1, CONCAT(':', record.$2))) AS company;
```

the error info are:

> [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Expecting
>   a bag of tuples: {()}, found data type: bytearray

Comment: bag = {(a,b), (c,d), (e,f)} BagToString(bag) --> 'a_b_c_d_e_f', bug I want get 'a:b_c:d_e:f'

Answer (score 0):

How about you separate the concat phase into two?

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS (id:int, company:chararray, rank:chararray);
B = GROUP A BY id;
C = FOREACH B {
    C2 = FOREACH A GENERATE CONCAT(CONCAT(company, ':'), rank);
    GENERATE group as id, C2;
}
D = FOREACH C GENERATE id, BagToString(C2);
STORE D into 'myfile';
```

Output

```
(1,b:2_a:1)
(2,a:4_c:3)
```

Comment: Great！This is what I want. Thank you！

Comment: @celia, Glad it worked for you. Please accept my answer when you get a chance.